# System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException with two 'parallel' proxies

Tags: wcf, web-services, jax-ws, mtom

My web services have been working perfectly, It's hard to tell what I did do that resulted in them crashing from time to time. I added HTTP Basic Authentication and swapped database providers, from ObjectDB to MySQL, so there was a drop in performance but this seems irrelevant.

I have SSL protected Java Metro web services hosted on GlassFish v3.1 with MTOM streaming enabled. I'm calling them with a WCF client. The exception occurs randomly from time to time even when I call the same service with the same parameters.

**UPDATE** Sometimes it just behaves like it makes a successful call, and then no matter which service I'm calling, even with a `helloWorld`, I'm getting the exception. If I call only one of the proxies, the calls go just fine, but for eg I get the exception, if I make a call to `dataMiningClient` and then `dataStoreClient`. Thread safety?

See:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = "";

    DataStoreWSClient dataStoreClient = getDataStoreClient(email, password);
    DataMiningWSClient dataMiningClient = getDataMiningClient(email, password);

    byte[] dataSet = File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text);
    string dataSetName = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);
    long checkSum = getCheckSumForDataSet(dataSet);

    //WS Call
    try
    {
        //Example: 
        //The second time I click on this button,
        //this is the point where I get the ProtocolException
        bool checkSumResponse = dataStoreClient.checkDataSet(checkSum);

        //checkSumResponse was always true when I was debugging this
        //So no MTOM streaming involved
        if (checkSumResponse)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = dataMiningClient.kNearestNeighbour(checkSum, notifyByEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = dataMiningClient.kNearestNeighbourMTOM(dataSetName, notifyByEmail, dataSet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        richTextBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

    dataMiningClient.Close();
    dataStoreClient.Close();
}
```

I do not have any error messages on the server side.

This is the exception message I get:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type multipart/related;start="";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:d64b0098-0dcb-4da4-a047-d305b55da9f5";start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '--uuid:d64b0098-0dcb-4da4-a047-d305b55da9f5
>       Content-Id: 
>       Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
>       Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <S:Header>
            <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</To>
            <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                    S:mustUnderstand="1">http://webServices/DataStoreWS/checkDataSetResponse</Action>
            <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:1cbcfdc6-01e4-4ddc-960d-a9a2d4e3021a</MessageID>
            <RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressin'. sender, EventArgs e) in F:\2.0\WSClient3.5ServiceRef\WSClient3.5\Form1.cs:line 51

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WSClient3._5.DataStore.DataStoreWS.checkDataSet(checkDataSetRequest request)
   at WSClient3._5.DataStore.DataStoreWSClient.WSClient3._5.DataStore.DataStoreWS.checkDataSet(checkDataSetRequest request) in F:\Dropbox\Suli\MSc\DIPLOMA_MSc\JavaWSJMX\2.0\WSClient3.5ServiceRef\WSClient3.5\Service References\DataStore\Reference.cs:line 1227
   at WSClient3._5.DataStore.DataStoreWSClient.checkDataSet(Int64 checkSum) in F:\Dropbox\Suli\MSc\DIPLOMA_MSc\JavaWSJMX\2.0\WSClient3.5ServiceRef\WSClient3.5\Service References\DataStore\Reference.cs:line 1233
   at WSClient3._5.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Dropbox\Suli\MSc\DIPLOMA_MSc\JavaWSJMX\2.0\WSClie
```

**Client Code**:

```
DataMiningWSClient getDataMiningClient(String username, String password)
{
    //IMPORTANT - THIS LINE IS ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES!
    //This code is for accepting self-signed server certificate
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender_ws, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    //instantiate transport binding element, leave the defaults
    HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
    transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
    transport.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;

    //instantiate message encoding element, where message version must be Soap11WSAddressing10 to match metro web service requirement.
    MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement mtom = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    mtom.WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mtom.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10;
    mtom.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
    mtom.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;

    //instantiate transport security binding element, with all the suggested values in app.config
    TransportSecurityBindingElement b_element = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
    b_element.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = new Basic128SecurityAlgorithmSuite();
    b_element.IncludeTimestamp = true;
    b_element.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.CombinedEntropy;
    b_element.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11;
    b_element.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;

    //instantiate the custom binding and add the elements created above
    CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
    customBinding.Name = "myOwnPersonalCustomBinding";
    customBinding.Elements.Add(b_element);
    customBinding.Elements.Add(mtom);
    customBinding.Elements.Add(transport);

    //instantiate the client 
    DataMiningWSClient DMclient = new DataMiningWSClient(customBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://localhost:8181/DataMiner/DataMiner")));
    setCredentials(username, password, DMclient.ClientCredentials);
    return DMclient;
}
```

Any hints what could be the problem here? Please tell me if I should extend this question with more info; I may dig into the WCF message logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of `ProtocolException`: I did NOT configure both proxies with an `MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement`, however both services were defined with the `@MTOM` annotation.

After defining it for both proxies everything worked fine:

```
//instantiate message encoding element, where message version must be Soap11WSAddressing10 to match metro web service requirement.
MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement mtom = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
mtom.WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mtom.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10;
mtom.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
mtom.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
```